# How can I unlock a Mac G4?

Tags: mac, passwords, reset, g4

I'm running into a problem with my Mac g4

I can't reset the password; I get an invalid prompt after doing the 'resetpassword' query. 
**Is there any other way to unlock the account?** It's a single user account.

I got Mac at yard sale and the people won't answer the door now ;( I'm frustrated!

Comment: What sort of password is it? Does it prevent you from booting into OS X? Can't you just wipe and reinstall the OS?

Comment: I dont have the original disk to install. The password is administrative type, any other idea? Thanku!

Comment: Does it have Recovery Mode (Command + R during restart) that will allow you to erase the HDD and download OS X from Apple? If you can't download a copy of the OS then you'll have to borrow or buy it.

Comment: Will try this N if Needed i will buy the os . Im new here i will vote answer up when i figure this out! Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to enter the recovery mode while restarting Mac, and then erase the Hard Disk Drive. Then you must install a new version of OS X on your Mac.

Attention: All your files will be deleted after erasing the HDD.

NOTE: Enter the recovery mode by pressing ⌘-R while restarting Mac.